# Java : logging execution history as XML

Tags: java, reflection, parameters, methods

For debugging purposes, I need to follow the execution of some piece of code, within a class. I would like to generate a log for all method calls, in XML, like :

```
<call class='pack.age.MyClass' method='myMethod1'>
    <param name='param1'>param1.toString() value</param>
    ...
    <call>Call to other method within myMethod1; you get the idea</call>
</call>
```

Because the class is **long** and has **lots** of methods, I wondered if there is a way to access the parameters generically, maybe using reflection. I am inside of the method, and I want  to loop on the parameters given to this call of the method. It would ease my pain and allow me to make a regexp to add the log lines. Is it possible ?

Any other neat way to do it appreciated (but AOP alas not really an option).

Comment: Why is AOP not an option? That's like saying OOP isn't an option.

Comment: And if this is for debugging purposes, why not use a debugger?

Comment: Yes skaffman. Debugger + notepad. Or even sysout all over the place. Sure it's not sexy, but it's works.

Comment: Dudes, be helpful please. AOP not an option because, OOP neither, I'm dealing with full-procedural Java here. And I'm trying to spare myself HOURS of F5-hitting.

Comment: @subtenante: we are *trying* to help, but ruling out the best option for no apparent reason is not helping us to help you. Do you actually know what AOP involves, or have you just written it off?

Comment: It involves adding library dependencies which I can't.

Comment: when i'm faced with a similiar problem nothing beats the notepad. just trace the code manually. it just look like you'll spend more time, but our brains are lazy and they will realise what's going on in the code just to avoid the dull job of logging

Comment: We did log in Xml for a while, then we changed our minds. The problem is that Xml is supposed to be complete (closing tags for example), and **logs are not complete** typically : during the execution, they can't be. And a crash also interrupts the logs, so it can't be complete either. And if you artificially complete it, then you can't add logs anymore! So we can see that we would need to be fighting xml here!! I suggest logging as structured text (whether CSV or otherwise), and having the reading tool transform it to whatever you want (it could be xml, or Xhtml, or whatever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is using a dynamic tracer like BTrace (similar to AOP, but outside of your code). Look at [BTrace's wiki](https://github.com/btraceio/btrace/wiki) for examples. There are even VisualVM Plugins to attach to running process making things easier. With the following BTrace code you get the method calls and its parameters (taken from the examples).

```
import com.sun.btrace.AnyType;
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.*;
import static com.sun.btrace.BTraceUtils.*;


@BTrace public class YourCalls {
    @OnMethod(clazz="pack.age.MyClass", method="myMethod1",
              location=@Location(value=Kind.CALL, clazz="/.*/", method="/.*/"))
    public static void o(AnyType[] args) { // all calls to methods
        printArray(args);
    }
}
```

Attaching BTrace to your running program is easy. First get the PID of your process using jps, after this call:

```
btrace PID YourCalls.java
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a call to `log()` at the beginning of every method. Within `log()` either throw an Exception (for Java 1.4) or use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` to get a stack trace.

This will give you an array of [`StackTraceElement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html). The element you're looking for is at index 1 (this is where `log()` was called). Use `getMethodName()` to get the name of the method. After that, you can use reflection to examine the method.

Unfortunately, this doesn't give you access to the real Java stack so you can't print the values of the parameters. One solution would be to simply copy them into the log call and use reflection on the method to figure out what they are. With Java 5, variable argument lists (`log(Object...args)`) is your friend.

The other option is using the [Java Debugger API](http://docs.rinet.ru/JaTricks/ch26.htm) and write a small debugger. In this case, `RemoteStackFrame` will contain the parameters and values.

If that's too much work, just use ten lines of AOP and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

**weird** suggestion:

1. Open eclipse
2. create a subclass of your class with the first class in the constructor
3. modifiy the config of eclipse : in the template where eclipse creates a delegate method, add a beginMyMethod(); and a endMyMethod(); surrounding the delegate.method();
4. ask eclipse to implements all the delegate methods. This solution won't work with the private and the static members.

something like:

```
 class A
   {
   public void sayHello()
       {
       System.err.println("OK");
       }
   }

 class B
   extends A
   {
   private A delegate;
   public B(A delegate) { this.delegate=delegate);}
   @Override
   public void sayHello()
       {
       beginMyMethod();
       delegate.sayHello();
       endMyMethod();
       }
   }
```